# generate a different number of columns based on input number

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Suppose I have some XML data that has an unknown number of sub-nodes. Is there a method that allows me to input the number of sub-nodes into the program as a parameter, and have it process them? current code is something like this

```
    SourceXML = LOAD '$input' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('$TopNode') as test:chararray;

test2 = LIMIT SourceXML 3;

test3 = FOREACH test2 GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(test,'<$tag1>(.*)</$tag1>',1),
    REGEX_EXTRACT(test,'<$tag2>(.*)</$tag2>',1);

dump test3;
```

however I may not know in advance how many simple elements there are in the target data (how many $tag# there are). I am hoping to use a .txt file containing parameters that looks something like this:

> input=/inputpath/lowerlevelsofpath
>
> numberSimpleElements=3
>
> tag1=tag1name
>
> tag2=tag2name
>
> tag3=tag3name

With a regex_extract being done on each tag in the input file

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: ended up attempting to write a python script that dynamically generated pig code. While this improved flexibility it didn't give me what I needed. As such I just went to write Java MapReduce code instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could do following

1. Split the text by some regex, so that each row now has value.
2. Generate (tag, value) for each row
3. Do a join between (tag, value)  and (list of tags)